# How to access the initial value of an initialized object?

Tags: java

I'm learning java at the moment and I've got a question about an object that got initialized and got a variable changed during the program execution.

```
public class Char {
private String name;
private int skill;
private int defense;
private int life;

private Weapon weapon = Weapon.FISTS;

private Potion potion = null;
```

So, I want this code to get the initial value of life that got initialized, but how would I access it?

```
    public boolean isWeak() {
    return life < this.life * 0.25;
}
```

So, this method is located in the Char class. I'm trying to get it to return a true value when it gets lower than 25%.

```
    while (hero.isAlive() && monster.isAlive()) {
        if (hero.isWeak() && hero.hasPotion()) {
            hero.sip();
        } else if (monster.isWeak() && monster.hasPotion()){
            monster.sip();
        } else {
            System.out.println(monster.isWeak());
            hero.attack(monster);
            if (monster.isAlive()) {
                monster.attack(hero);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Here is the execution program. All the other methods work just fine, but as pointed out, it'll never return true because it can't be a quarter of itself. Don't mind the prints, I'm just testing it.

Comment: Can you post a more complete picture of your code? Doesn't have to include all the irrelevant details, but it is important for us to know where your methods are located relatively to your class.

Comment: At the moment, you only show one variable called 'life' - both `life` and `this.life` resolve to the member variable; obviously it is never less than an quarter of itself.  Either you've omitted some code, or else you're confused about variables.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. Guess it's the second, I'm a bit confused about variables. Is there a way to access the initial value of Life in the isWeak() method?

Comment: No, make a second variable to store the initial value. That's the way you do it. Java isn't going to remember every value a field held over its lifetime

Comment: Is there a method that can store it in the Char class even if the object wasn't initialized yet or it can only be done on the main program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you need to create a second variable that stores the value passed into the constructor:

```java
public class Char {
    private String name;
    private int skill;
    private int defense;
    private int initialLife;
    private int life;
    private Weapon weapon = Weapon.FISTS;
    private Potion potion = null;

    public Char(int initialLife //I am excluding all the other parameters you want to pass in
    ) {
        this.life = initialLife;
        this.initialLife = initialLife;
    }
    public boolean isWeak() {
        return life < this.initialLife * 0.25;
    }

}
```

As you can see, I store the initial life and I don't ever modify it. Since I modify the `life` variable, I can't use it to keep track of the initial value. Modifying a variable is a destructive process, and Java doesn't have a way to keep track of the history of variable values (unless you do it yourself as shown above).

Comment: Thank you, I was gonna do that but was expecting that there could be some other easier way.

Comment: @RicardoMuraoka Happy to help. If this solved your question, remember to accept it as an answer and upvote. Thanks!

Comment: If you're "never modifying" it, then you should declare it final - that is the real guarantee that the program won't ever modify your variable any longer.